# CSS absolute button has input field "pushing" through the button

Tags: css

I have a button I've designed to appear on my web page after a certain amount of input inactivity. The button covers the entire page with the following CSS:

```
.continue {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(5, 89, 158, 0.7);
  color: #000;
}
```

It covers the entire web page successfully, however input fields are "pushing" through the button so that when you should be able to click on the button to continue, you instead click on an input field. Disabling input fields doesn't seem to put my button the top.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you also show us the relevant HTML, please?

Comment: Have you considered using [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)? And what actually _is_ the element that has class `continue`? Provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: creating a sandbox or fiddle will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated above, the issue is probably a conflict between z-indexes. Z-index determines the stacking order of elements, sort of like layers in illustrator or photoshop. By setting a higher z-index, (in the context of absolutely or fixed positioned elements), you ensure they appear 'on top' of elements with lower (or default) z-index values. Try setting the z-index of your button to 999 for testing purposes.

See: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index for documentation.